# Cannot post images

Tags: support, new-users, images

I was trying to post photos (diagram) to clarify the ideas, but I coudn't do that because of the following:

> We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

I guess it's 2 reasons:

- You have to have more than 10 reputation points. (Which I have)
- You cannot be a new user. (Which I am)

What do I have to do to become a non-new user? Is it related to time (how much time?) or is it related to reputation (how many points?)

Comment: You do not have 10 rep on any site. Is it possible that you are not logged in to the account you normally use?

Comment: [Your profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/357782/rajura) indicates that you (or at least the account you are currently logged in as) do not have 10 reputation on any site, although the account has existed on SO for at least 14 days (not sure if that time period gives you any hints). Can you find and post a link to one of the posts you *previously* made with your older >10 rep account?

Comment: @peterh: If I had to guess, it's because the OP's first assumption is trivially falsifiable: they *don't* have 10 rep, and that is incredibly simple to verify by looking at the topbar.

Comment: @peterh ... which you continue to be happy to be a part of. Do you think that, maybe, just maybe, you could consider not inserting some sort of comment about how much you apparently hate the community in *every single post you comment on, ever*? There are times and places to pick battles. It *is* possible to contribute positively to a post without turning it in to yet another way for you to make a statement about your feelings towards the community that you are a part of. When you constantly poke and prod, you don't get to complain if eventually you're met with defensive hostility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the thing here is that you need 10 rep on any site to post images.

According to your profile, you don't:

[image]

Being a "new" user really doesn't matter to the message. What matters is getting your reputation to at least 10. You could get it now or a year later, all you need is to have at least 10 reputation to post images.

Answer (score 2):

You're a new user. We don't know whether you're an acceptable bag of organic meat or a can of processed spam. Upvotable activity determines whether you're a real person or not. 10 reputation is literally one answer vote or 2 question votes which in *theory* is trivial to obtain.

Post the answer as best as you can with a *link* to your image. Many new users go "I don't have the reputation needed to post an image but...." so people know its there. Make sure its on imgur - other image hosts don't always work well. Chances are someone would edit in the image for you, say off the review queues.